# What's the difference between "./" and "../"?

Tags: node.js, nwjs

What does `./` mean? I assume that it is used to search a path, but I am not sure if that is true. I know that, for example, in C# if I want to search a path I can use `../../file.exe`.

Currently what I want is to run a command in `node.js` from my application in `NW.js` with the following code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('node ./server.js', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ', stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ', stderr);

    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ', error);
    }
});
```

However, the code above does not produce the desired results. I believe it is because I don't know how to search the path of `server.js` that I want to run.

Comment: `./` is the current directory, `../` is the parent of the current directory.

Comment: Why not add your comment as an answer?

Comment: I thought someone would have closed this question as a duplicate, this question has been asked quite often, but I was wrong. @JonathanSoifer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using some form of `*NIX`.

`./` is your current directory. So, for example, using `cd ./examplefolder` is perfectly valid.

`../` is the parent directory. So, for example, you can use `cd ../` to go up a level in the directory hierarchy.

`~` is your home directory. So, if you're at `~/example/example2/example3`, you can use `cd ~/` to return to home quickly.

If you're using nodejs, simply using the command `node yourfilehere.js` will execute it, if your current directory is the one you're launching the file from. Using `node ../yourfilehere.js` works just as well... but then again, so does `cd ../` and `node yourfilehere.js`.

Comment: Is it alright if I update the wording of the last section in your answer? It's somewhat misleading.

Comment: Yeah, go ahead. Belatedly.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of `node.js`, I'll go into a little bit more detail than the commenter.

`./` means that you should execute a file in the current directory. To see the current directory and if you're on unix, type `pwd`. `../` will mean execute a file in the "previous" directory. In graph theory this would mean the parent node.

If you don't specify a path to the executable, then the system will look in the PATH

Comment: I know this is true for Linux commands and scripts executed directly. But is it really also true for the argument passed to node?